# Npm; is package-lock.json redundant if package.json only specifies exact versions?

Tags: npm, versioning

I struggle with npm's `package.json` and `package-lock.json` duality. I believe this question may provide insight regarding how these files relate to each other:

**If** we define a `package.json` file which *only specifies exact versions for all dependencies*, e.g.:

```
...
  "dependencies": {
    "dep1": "1.2.3",
    "dep2": "4.5.6"
  }
...
```

and never any ambiguous versions, such as:

```
...
  "dependencies": {
    "dep1": "^1.2.3",
    "dep2": "4.5.*"
  }
...
```

**then** would there ever be a reason to also maintain a `package-lock.json` file? (And if so, what is such a reason?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `package-lock.json` is not redundant even if you pin specific version of your dependency.

`package-lock.json` protects you from transitive dependencies - [any dependency that is induced by the components that the program references directly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_dependency).

> [It describes the exact tree that was generated, such that subsequent installs are able to generate identical trees, regardless of intermediate dependency updates](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/configuring-npm/package-lock-json)

For example:

1. A → B
2. It is not the case that B → A
3. B → C

Then the dependency A → C (which follows from 1 and 3 by the axiom of transitivity) is a transitive dependency.

Note that B can use any non-exact version constraint on C, such as `>= X`. So it might be that when C dependency is resolved, each time it can be **any** version bigger than X. `package-lock.json` will guarantee that is not the case.