# Is it needed to have a lock file if I fix versions of all dependencies?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, package.json

I have a NodeJs/Typescript project and I fixed versions of all deps like this

```json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "eslint": "8.30.0",
    "prettier": "2.8.1",
    "turbo": "1.6.3",
    "typescript": "4.9.4"
  }
}
```

Do I need yarn.lock or package-lock.json any more? I assume it will install the same version of deps everytime I run installation.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, you should always use a lock file. It also tracks sub dependencies, for example. And if the lock system is good, it will also use checksums and such. But at the end of the day, this may be an opinion based question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Npm; is package-lock.json redundant if package.json only specifies exact versions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66067402/npm-is-package-lock-json-redundant-if-package-json-only-specifies-exact-version)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, because those packages may have specified *their* dependencies in a looser way; for instance, [eslint 8.30.0's `package.json`](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/blob/v8.30.0/package.json#L57-L97) specifies all of the runtime dependencies with `^`.

The lock file ensures that top-level dependencies *and* transitive dependencies are locked to specific versions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you'd better to use it.

It awoids unwanted transitive dependencies updates. This is important, as they may, albeit rarely, get poisoned.

For example, our security flags `es5-ext` as protestware, so we have to force-limit its version in our apps